# Calculate the number of occurrences of a column value value *per* unique id

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the number of occurrences of a columnvalue *per* unique id and store them in a new panda Dataframe:

Dataframe (simplified):

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Keywords are +1.000s and not known. Have tried by creating lists and zipping them, but not really working.

Comment: What have you tried involving `pandas`? You just want to look into `groupby` operations.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['unique id'],df['keyword'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` `apply` with `Counter`,`untack` and `fillna`:

```
from collections import Counter
df.groupby('unique id')['keyword'].apply(Counter).to_frame().unstack(1).fillna(0)

          keyword            
             auto fish mobile
unique id                    
1a            2.0  1.0    1.0
2a            1.0  2.0    1.0
3a            0.0  1.0    0.0
```